# How to get a string after specific character and before specific character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, select

I would like to obtain a string from a larger string. The string to be obtained is delimited by specific characters.

For example, if field1 is "lipnice sivá <(Poa glauca)>"

I want it to return "Poa glauca"

What would this select statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the base string function `SUBSTRING_INDEX` we can try:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX('lipnice sivá <(Poa glauca)>', '<(', -1), ')>', 1);
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can `REGEXP_REPLACE` for a regex based solution:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('lipnice sivá <(Poa glauca)>', '^.*<\\((.*?)\\)>.*$', '$1');
```

Follow the demo link below to see both queries.

### Demo